# Use current SQLite database after app rewrite in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I have an app built in Java and I want to rewrite it to Flutter. I want to keep the old database to "migrate" it to the new one in Flutter.

When I check the data in the app folder (data/data/my.package.name/databases/database.db) it seems that the new app in Flutter override the folder so the old database dissapear.

When I re-install the old app in Java, all my data are present so the old database seems to be kept by the Os but I don't know where.

There is someone that was doing the same thing as me: [Update an (native) android app with a new version in Flutter while keeping the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52107772/update-an-native-android-app-with-a-new-version-in-flutter-while-keeping-the-d)
 but it doesn't work for me.

Is there a way I can achieve such thing?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The new app should have the same `<package_name>` if you want to "see" the previous data by the old app.

Comment: It does have the same package name :/